# Load partials based on action parameter in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I want to load a partial view in Phalcon based on the route parameter.

I have this action, which determines the name of the partial:

```
public function addAction($discipline = null)
{
    if (isset($discipline)) {
        $this->view->partial = 'add' . $discipline . '.phtml';
    } else {
        $this->view->partial = 'addstatic.phtml';
    }
}
```

And in the main view, I want to load this partial with the Volt-command `partial`, like so:

```
{{ partial('partials/training/' ~ partial) }}
```

But I am facing this error:

```
View 'C:\xampp\htdocs\apneist_social/app/views/partials/training/addstatic.phtml' was not found in the views directory
```

If I browse to this file with the directory browser, I can find the file though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extension (.phtml). Like:

```
$this->view->partial = 'addstatic';
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Wait a minute, why you using volt and want to use phtml in addstatic ? Use volt everwhere :D

Comment: Well, I use volt inside of the .phtml files. :) you can tell Phalcon which ending you are using for your views, I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: Oh okay, then it's fine :)